# migrating ubuntu system to a different machine

Tags: apt, dpkg, migration

I wish to migrate my Ubuntu system, the source system to an existing Ubuntu system, the target system. They run 12.04 and 14.04 respectively. Basically, I want all (or most if that is the best we can do) of the programs that I have installed on my system to be available on the existing Ubuntu system. Most programs I have downloaded are from `apt-get` but I have built some programs from source. I don't really care too much about custom settings.

What makes my question different from other [questions][1] is that I want the target system to keep its programs. The solutions I have seen do a `dpkg clear-selections on the target system,` which will mark all packages that are not critical to `deinstall.` Hence, all programs on the target system will be removed upon `dselect upgrade.`

I am being cautious and asking on this site because I do not want to delete everything on my target system.

Is the following a valid solution:

1. get a list of installed programs from the source system
2. generate a list of the `diff` of the programs installed on the target system with the source system
3. Install the list from the previous step on the target system.

Comment: That seems about right.